# Is there a way to modularize code with the ability to run both asynchronously and on the main thread?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Suppose I have an object I've created.  We'll call it `MyObject`.

I'd like to be able to save `MyObject` to a database's corresponding table.  I don't want this to happen on the `Activity`'s main thread.  Easy enough.  I created an `AsyncTask` to do this.

However, my application also has an `IntentService` used to sync data between the device's database and my cloud database.  I'd like to save `MyObject`s that have synced down from the cloud to the device's database from here, too.  However, I do not wish for this to happen asynchronously in the `IntentService`.  I want it to happen on the `IntentService`'s main thread.

The purpose, obviously, is to modularize this code so it doesn't need to be duplicated.

How can I modularize my save code so that it can be called both asynchronously and synchronously?

I suspect I will create a `saveMe()` method inside the `MyObject` and declare it a `static`.  From the `IntentService`, I simply call `saveMe()`.  From an `Activity`, I will launch an `AsyncTask` which passes in the `MyObject` and then calls `saveMe()`.  Does that sound right?

Comment: That's about right, but why do you think `saveMe()` needs to be static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the `static` that sounds good to me, don't you wish to access instance variables?

I don't know how your application is designed in general, but I'd probably go for one of the  following patterns:

- a subclass of `Runnable` (or `Callable` if you need return values and/or exceptions) that handles saving in general, with a suitable factory or constructor. You can then run these tasks directly or on background threads.
- instances of objects have a method to save themselves (this is what you described), and these methods are used by synchronous or asynchronous code.
- instances of databases / storage classes have a method to save `MyObject` instances, assuming they have a common parent class where you can put that code, and these methods are used by synchronous or asynchronous code.

The exact pattern depends on the application you're working on imho.

Answer (score 0):

When I'm in a situation where I sometimes want to do something synchronously and sometimes asynch:

I tend to implement an `IntentService` with a public static method to do what I want usually called `blockingX` where `X` is what it does. This way, if I want to do it synchronously, I call the method directly. If I want to do it on a background thread, I send the service an intent.